# Unable to connect to artifactory after service restart on CentOS7

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, artifactory

I'm a total linux newbie and I'll drop the story here so hopefully someone knows what's going on.

I have a linux box running CentOS and I have artifactory running as a service. After I restarted the server everything started back up but I'm no longer able to connect to artifactory. I checked the artifactory log and everything says it started fine

artifactory.log

```
2017-02-09 22:15:12,149 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.s.ArtifactoryApplicationContext:360) - Artifactory application context is ready.
2017-02-09 22:15:12,152 [art-init] [INFO ] (o.a.w.s.ArtifactoryContextConfigListener:225) -
###########################################################
### Artifactory successfully started (7.122 seconds)    ###
###########################################################
```

Then I checked the tomcat log to make sure that that started fine

catalina.log

```
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.56
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:42 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deploying configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDescriptor
INFO: Deployment of configuration descriptor /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/conf/Catalina/localhost/artifactory.xml has finished in 4,865 ms
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:47 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory /opt/jfrog/artifactory/tomcat/webapps/ROOT has finished in 246 ms
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8081"]
Feb 09, 2017 10:25:47 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol start
INFO: Starting ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8019"]
```

I'm at a point where I'm not even sure what to check. When I try to connect to the page I just get the "The Connection has time out".

If anyone knows anything I can check I'd be extremely grateful.

edit:

Running a netstat -tulnp it shows the ports as open

```
tcp6       0      0 127.0.0.1:8015          :::*                    LISTEN      3538/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8081                 :::*                    LISTEN      3538/java
tcp6       0      0 :::8019                 :::*                    LISTEN      3538/java
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had a firewall on.

Since this is an internal site I disabled it by

```
systemctl stop firewalld
```

Would it be worth my time to just allow those ports access?

Comment: The short answer is yes. The longer answer is that today this is an isolated site, but maybe tomorrow it will be opened to the Internet.  So my suggestion is to do it properly.